Using ULIDs in DynamoDB for storing telemetry data in order of receipt
I am working in a system where in which IoT devices connect and send packets containing telemetry data.
The devices timestamp the telemetry reports with a one second resolution however they also provide a "sequence number" indicating their order, to help detect duplicates etc. The sequence number is a wrapping byte, I.E. 253,254,255,0,1.
I am storing the data in DynamoDB and would like to use a ULID as the sort key to maintain the order but create uniqueness because it is likely you could receive multiple reports within the same second.
I have to assume an ephemeral environment where in which the creation of my ULID can rely on only the second resolution timestamp and the sequence number.
Creating a ULID from the timestamp should in most cases, be okay. But how can I ensure the ULID ordering when there are multiple reports within the same second?
I have theorised maybe seeding the ULID slightly by just incrementing the second resolution timestamp by the sequence number in milliseconds.
There are two issues with this solution:

The true source value of the ULID is somewhat lost.


This is not a massive issue, with it only being one second resolution, a maximum increment of     255ms would not deface the data but it still seems like a hacky workaround.


The edge case where the sequence number rolls over is not appropriately addressed. If I had three reports:

Time: 2024-09-28T22:36:19+00:00, Sequence: 254 Time: 2024-09-28T22:36:19+00:00, Sequence: 255 Time: 2024-09-28T22:36:19+00:00, Sequence: 0
The third, actually most recent report, will be assigned a ULID that is lexicographically lesser to it's previous siblings.

I can safely assume that there would not be more than 999 reports within the same second and that I am able to process each report sequentially and synchronously. If I can externally store my own wrapping sequence number between zero and 999, perhaps I could "seed" the ULID by incrementing the milliseconds with this number.

I would need to reset this number whenever the source second increments to avoid the same wrapping edge-case within my own sequence number

According to the specifications, ULID have milliseconds resolution. Given you are not expecting more than 999 reports within the same second this may be okay.

Timestamp
48 bit integer
UNIX-time in milliseconds
Won't run out of space 'til the year 10889 AD.

However, if you are running into issues where you need to bucket data in sub-millisecond records; it is possible to devise your own lexicographically sortable timestamp & random value encoding, similar to a ULID, but replacing the randomness by a specific sequence since reading from a good source of randomness may be expensive by itself, at that resolution.
The scheme could take the following form, using a random value read from a sufficiently good source of randomness and an atomic integer sequence:

At application start, read R bits from a reliable source of randomness
Initialize the atomic integer sequence to 0
With each new record to store:

Create an empty byte array
Push the microsecond resolution timestamp into the byte array (with MSB ordering)
Push the random value into the byte array
Push current integer sequence's first N bits at the back of the array
Increment the integer sequence atomically
Encode the byte array into a string; with, for example, the ring containing all letters and digits.



Vary the values of R & N to the desired size. The source of randomness is needed to ensure that records stored from each virtual machine or process does not collide with any other record stored at the same time, during the same sequence.
